# Run a prerequisite silently along with application setup in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

I am trying to create a setup of my application along with all of it's prerequisites.

I want iTunes as prerequisite for my application, and want to install it silently along with my application. i.e. I want to install my prerequisite silently.

I have made bootstrap package for iTunes(now it is appearing in prerequisites list) and made by set up.

The set up is asking for installation of iTunes when it is run.

I want my iTunes set up to run silently along with the application setup.

Now it is showing dialog box :

> "The following components will be installed on your machine: 
>   [Component List]  Do you wish to install these components? If you
>   choose Cancel, setup will exit.  [Install Button] [Cancel Button]"

I am using `Visual Studio 2010 install project` (this is not an install shield project).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that message:

"The following components will be installed on your machine: [Component List] Do you wish to install these components? If you choose Cancel, setup will exit. [Install Button] [Cancel Button]"

is not from the setup.exe, or your MSI setup, so it must be coming from one of your prereqs like iTunes, but the component names are not shown so I've no idea which one. Either way, it looks like your silent install command line is in fact not silent. Don't assume that they are all the same.

Comment: Yes the pop up message is coming from the prereq Itunes
in component list only itunes.exe is shown.

Comment: In that case you just need the real iTunes silent command line, assuming there is one. This isn't a Visual Studio issue. This was the first thing I see in a search   https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2729053?tstart=0

Comment: I tried the lnk that u mentioned above.
it telling about making a batch file. I tried to make a batch file, but how to run a batch file with a setup..this i could not find out..please help me out

Comment: The batch file contains commands, look at those. For example, it says to run the MSI files with /qn and that is a silent install!

Comment: I tried that too... i tried with /qn also..still not able to do.